# How to extract data from redis Do() result

Tags: go, redis, interface

Given I have: `"github.com/go-redis/redis"` package and I use it's method to fire custom Redis cmd: https://godoc.org/github.com/go-redis/redis#Client.Do

I end up with:

```
result, err := client.Do("MEMORY", "STATS").Result()
```

`result` is looking as follows:

```
<interface {}>
 data:<[]interface {}> (length: 52, cap: 52)
  [0]:<interface {}>
   data:"peak.allocated"
  [1]:<interface {}>
   data:4957760
  [2]:<interface {}>
    data:"total.allocated"
  [3]:<interface {}>
    data:855632
  [4]:<interface {}>
  //... and so on
```

Basically, it's a interface with a data property, and within data we have more interfaces (even are keys, and odd's are values).

I would like to type it so I can get value of `"total.allocated"`.

What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is specific to the [`MEMORY STATS`](https://redis.io/commands/memory-stats) redis command. Its result is an array, *"the information about memory usage is provided as metrics and their respective values "*.

Since there is no "predefined" type to model this, simply use a [type-assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to acquire the slice in Go, iterate over it, and look for the key you're interested in: `"total.allocated"`. The subsequent slice element will be the value you're looking for.

This is how you can do it:

```
result, err := client.Do("MEMORY", "STATS").Result()
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
    return
}
if stats, ok := result.([]interface{}); ok {
    for i := 0; i < len(stats); i += 2 {
        if stats[i] == "total.allocated" && i+1 < len(stats) {
            fmt.Println("total allocated memory:", stats[i+1])
        }
    }
}
```

We can simplify the loop if we loop until `len-1` (instead of `len`), so we don't have to check if `i+1` is valid index:

```
for i, max := 0, len(stats)-1; i < max; i += 2 {
    if stats[i] == "total.allocated" {
        fmt.Println("total allocated memory:", stats[i+1])
    }
}
```

The value of total allocated memory is a value of type `int64`. If you need it as a number, use another type-assertion:

```
allocated := stats[i+1].(int64)
```

Or to be safe:

```
if allocated, ok := stats[i+1].(int64); ok {
    // Use allocated
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Redigo has a helper just for that: https://github.com/gomodule/redigo/blob/master/redis/reply.go#L377

In pseudo-Golang it looks like this:

```
result, err := redis.StringMap(client.Do("MEMORY", "STATS"), err)
```